# How to invoke a function when a class is instantiated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two classes, one of which is a subclass of the other. What I want to do is have one of the functions, step, invoked when the subclass is instantiated. This will cause the subclass to blink. I can see how to do it with functional instantiation but not with pseudoclassical. I've attached the jquery and javascript. Basically, when the button is clicked, I want the blinky dancer to blink, this should happen via the step function. Maybe I'm calling it incorrectly in the dancer superclass?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.dancers = [];

  $('.addDancerButton').on('click', function(event) {

    var dancerMakerFunctionName = $(this).data('dancer-maker-function-name');
    console.log(dancerMakerFunctionName);

    var dancerMakerFunction = window[dancerMakerFunctionName];


    var dancer = new dancerMakerFunction(
      $("body").height() * Math.random(),
      $("body").width() * Math.random(),
      Math.random() * 1000
    );
    $('body').append(dancer.$node);
  });
});



var makeBlinkyDancer = function(top, left, timeBetweenSteps) {
  makeDancer.call(this, top, left, timeBetweenSteps);
};

makeBlinkyDancer.prototype = Object.create(makeDancer.prototype);
makeBlinkyDancer.prototype.constructor = makeBlinkyDancer;

var oldStep = makeBlinkyDancer.prototype.step;

makeBlinkyDancer.prototype.step = function() {
  oldStep();
  this.$node.toggle();
};

var makeDancer = function(top, left, timeBetweenSteps) {
  this.$node = $('<span class="dancer"></span>');
};
makeDancer.prototype.step = function() {
  setTimeout(step.bind(this), timeBetweenSteps);
};



makeDancer.prototype.setPosition = function (top, left) {
  var styleSettings = {
    top: top,
    left: left
  };
  this.$node.css(styleSettings);
};

// makeDancer.prototype.setPosition();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where is `oldStep()` defined? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! I took a stab at answering your question. If you encountered a specific issue or error you need to resolve, please feel free to update the question with the complete code. However, I inferred from your question that the main objective is to create a subclass that blinks upon instantiation, and that your current approach might be taking you the wrong direction. I did my best to keep parts of your example code while still creating a clear working example. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the method when the subclass is instantiated by calling `init` in the constructor. In the example and demo I called this method `makeBlink` rather than `step` or `oldStep`. Hope that makes it clear.

```
// the subclass BlinkyDancer
var BlinkyDancer = function (top, left, height, width, timeBetweenSteps) {
  // ... get props from parent class

  // make blink when sublcass instantiated
  this.init = this.makeBlink();
};
```

### Full Demo/Solution

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/call-method-when-class-instantiated-mnesxt

#### HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <button id="make-blink">Make Blink</button>
    <button id="stop-blink">Stop Blink</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### JS

```
import $ from "jquery";

var Dancer = function (top, left, height, width) {
  this.$node = $('<div class="dancer"></div>');
  this.top = top;
  this.left = left;
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
  this.bg = "blue";
};

Dancer.prototype.putDancerOnScreen = function () {
  this.$node.height(this.height).width(this.width);
  this.$node.css("background-color", "blue");
  this.$node.css("position", "absolute");
  $("body").append(this.$node);
};

Dancer.prototype.setPosition = function () {
  this.$node.css("top", this.top);
  this.$node.css("left", this.left);
};

var myDancer = new Dancer(
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
  50,
  50
);
myDancer.putDancerOnScreen();
myDancer.setPosition();

// the subclass BlinkyDancer
var BlinkyDancer = function (top, left, height, width, timeBetweenSteps) {
  Dancer.call(this, top, left, height, width); // get the props set up by Dancer
  this.timeBetweenSteps = timeBetweenSteps;
  this.blinkerId = null;

  // make blink when sublcass instantiated
  this.init = this.makeBlink();
};

// set inheritance and Dancer constructor function
BlinkyDancer.prototype = Object.create(Dancer.prototype);
BlinkyDancer.prototype.constructor = Dancer;

// add subclass methods
BlinkyDancer.prototype.makeBlink = function () {
  if (this.blinkerId !== null) {
    return;
  }
  let count = 0;
  let blinkerId = setInterval(() => {
    // do whatever thing you want to indicate blinking/dancing
    if (count % 2 === 0) {
      this.$node.css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
      this.$node.css("background-color", "blue");
    }
    count++;
  }, this.timeBetweenSteps);

  this.blinkerId = blinkerId;
  console.log("blinkder id set: ", this.blinkerId);
};

BlinkyDancer.prototype.stopBlink = function () {
  if (this.blinkerId === null) {
    // already blinking
    return;
  }
  if (this.blinkerId !== null) {
    clearInterval(this.blinkerId);
    console.log("blink id cleared: ", this.blinkerId);
    this.blinkerId = null;
  }
};

// instantiate a new subclass
let myBlinkyDancer = new BlinkyDancer(
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
  50,
  50,
  25
);

// use parent class methods to put the element on screen
myBlinkyDancer.putDancerOnScreen();
myBlinkyDancer.setPosition();

const makeBlinkButton = document.getElementById("make-blink");
const stopBlinkButton = document.getElementById("stop-blink");

makeBlinkButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  myBlinkyDancer.makeBlink();
});

stopBlinkButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  myBlinkyDancer.stopBlink();
});
```

### Explanation

The `Dancer` class takes some props related to positioning and dimensions. It gets a blue background and has two methods for adding the element to the DOM and setting the position on screen.

`BlinkyDancer` is a subclass that inherits all the props of `Dancer` as well as two new props and two new methods.

> What I want to do is have one of the functions, step, invoked when the
> subclass is instantiated.

When a new `BlinkyDancer` is instantiated, we call `makeBlink` right away with `init` so the element starts blinking.

```
// make blink when sublcass instantiated
this.init = this.makeBlink();
```

I used an alternating background color to demonstrate the blinking effect.

The `makeBlink` and `stopBlink` methods work in tandem with the new props `timeBetweenSteps` and `blinkerId`.

> when the button is clicked, I want the blinky dancer to blink, this
> should happen via the step function.

Buttons are wired up to trigger starting and stopping the blinking effect. I've replaced `step` in your example with simple and declarative methods for making the blink and stopping it.

```
makeBlinkButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  myBlinkyDancer.makeBlink();
});
```

The blinking effect uses `setInterval` to toggle the background color using the `timeBetweenSteps` prop as the interval duration. `startBlink` starts the interval and sets `blinkerId` to the corresponding interval ID. To stop the blinking effect, `clearInterval` is passed the `blinkerId` to clear it (stopping the blinking effect) before resetting it to null.

```
BlinkyDancer.prototype.makeBlink = function () {
  if (this.blinkerId !== null) {
    return;
  }
  let count = 0;
  let blinkerId = setInterval(() => {
    // do whatever thing you want to indicate blinking/dancing
    if (count % 2 === 0) {
      this.$node.css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
      this.$node.css("background-color", "blue");
    }
    count++;
  }, this.timeBetweenSteps);

  this.blinkerId = blinkerId;
  console.log("blinkder id set: ", this.blinkerId);
};

BlinkyDancer.prototype.stopBlink = function () {
  if (this.blinkerId === null) {
    // already blinking
    return;
  }
  if (this.blinkerId !== null) {
    clearInterval(this.blinkerId);
    console.log("blink id cleared", this.blinkerId);
    this.blinkerId = null;
  }
};
```

> Maybe I'm calling [`step`] incorrectly in the dancer superclass?

It looks like you were on the right track but missing parens to call the method. In your example code, rather than:

```
makeBlinkyDancer.prototype.step;
```

You would do:

```
makeBlinkyDancer.prototype.step();
```